# javax.mail Sending email fails due to HELO/EHLO argument "localhost," invalid

Tags: server, localhost, jakarta-mail

I am using `javax.mail` to send emails from my backend to my personal email address (I wanna get a notification in case something particular happens). 
On my local machine (that is in debug/development mode) this works fine. But on my production server I am encountering the following problem:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.5
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q2sm11403478qtf.52 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587

EHLO localhost,
501-5.5.4 HELO/EHLO argument "localhost," invalid, closing connection.
501 5.5.4  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=helo q2sm11403478qtf.52 - gsmtp
HELO localhost,
DEBUG SMTP: EOF: [EOF]
javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2215)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.helo(SMTPTransport.java:1599)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:705)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
```

Obviously `HELO/EHLO argument "localhost," invalid` is the problem. I first thought I had to change me `/etc/hosts` entries. But actually they should be okay, they are like this:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost, myremotemachine
87.85.108.234   myremotemachine

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

So, I mapped my servername to the `127.0.0.1` and on my public ip address. Also, in the console the command `hostname` outputs `myremotemachine`.

So, what else do I have to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there should be no commas between names in the /etc/hosts file.

You can move the 87.85.108.234 entry above the localhost entry, or remove myremotemachine from the localhost entry, or set the JavaMail [mail.smtp.localhost](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html#mail.smtp.localhost) property to the name you want to use.